# Magento 2 checkout 'shipping-information' response

Tags: magento2, checkout, response

In checkout page when we click Next button from shipping step, we can see a response named shipping-information that contains payment methods and totals information. Where is this response come and can i access/modify the response?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify following class

```
Magento/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php
```

**saveAddressInformation** Method return payment info and total.

You can modify this class using plugin.

Answer (score 6):

This is a response from Checkout Web API entry point:

`/V1/guest-carts/:cartId/shipping-information` - [GuestShippingInformationManagementInterface::saveAddressInformation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Api/GuestShippingInformationManagementInterface.php#L19) for guest customer

`/V1/carts/mine/shipping-information` - [ShippingInformationManagementInterface::saveAddressInformation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Api/ShippingInformationManagementInterface.php#L19) for logged customer.

`/V1/carts/:cartId/shipping-information` - [ShippingInformationManagementInterface::saveAddressInformation](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Api/ShippingInformationManagementInterface.php#L19) for logged customer.

All Checkout Web API entry points are specified in [webapi.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Checkout/etc/webapi.xml).

To customize this response, you need to create own Web API services and override Checkout entry points in your custom `webapi.xml` or use plugins for API interfaces implementations, but you must be sure what you won't broke Magento Checkout js components.